# GKO construction for (Super-)Virasoro algebras

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras, mp.mathematical-physics, string-theory, lie-superalgebras

I am reading the paper "Unitary Representations of the Virasoro and Super-Virasoro Algebras" by Goddard, Kent, Olive. In many places, the authors claim results without any justification, or with obscure justifications. Is there a textbook or article which summarized and/or digested the contents of this paper?

Comment: Victor Kac: *Infinite dimensional Lie algebras: an introduction*.

Comment: For the Neveu-Schwarz (N=1 Super-Virasoro algebra), see Section 2 in  [arXiv:1010.0077](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.0077.pdf), coming from my [PhD dissertation](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00514234/document).